# Xamarin Forms Aar Library Implementation Problem

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I added aar library to XF project. I create callback class for a method that I want to use from aar library which I've added.  The aar interface, which I created callback class in, also implements its own methods as well as IBinder AsBinder() method. I read [Bound Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/bound-services) documents thus I tried to create Service class but callback didn't work.

I also tried:

```
public IBinder AsBinder()
{
  return new Binder();
}
```

but it didn't work again. Lastly, I tried:

```
public IBinder AsBinder()
{
   return CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window.DecorView.WindowToken;
}
```

but I got "Throw securityException(Binder invocation to an incorrect interface)" as result.

How should I use AsBinder method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found stub class in aar and i used as a binder.

```
[Register ("asBinder", "()Landroid/os/IBinder;", "GetAsBinderHandler")]
public virtual IBinder AsBinder ()
{
    try {
        JniObjectReference val = _members.get_InstanceMethods ().InvokeVirtualObjectMethod ("asBinder.()Landroid/os/IBinder;", this, null);
        return Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<IBinder> (val.get_Handle (), JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
    } finally {
    }
}
```